# VBA code to autoupdate cell with current date, when cell changed, not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet where I daily change the stats of some rows and I have to know when the stats changed. To make my life easier, I found on the internet this VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("R1:R2000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date

End Sub
```

The code works wonderfully. Everytime I change de stats on column R, it update the date on column S.

The problem is that I change this stat in a table linked to an outside source (Oracle Database) and if I try to refresh the table, it change the entire content of the table to different dates. What I have to do now is, everytime I have to refresh the table, I just comment the entire VBA Code.

Is there anything I can change on the code so it doesn't update when I refresh the table?

Edit 1:

```
Sub RefreshOracleTable()
    Application.EnableEvents = False


    If Intersect(Target, Range("R1:R200000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("wsTables").ListObjects("OracleTable").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disable events, then refresh table

You can write a Sub, which you will use for refreshing the table. Before refresh you will disable excel events. Like so:

```
Sub RefreshOracleTable
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'the refresh itself code something like
    Thisworkbook.Sheets("wsTables").ListObjects("OracleTable").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Application.EnableEvents = TRUE
End Sub
```

### Manual entry of a Date with Keyboard shortcut

Consider using a Keyboard shortcut to manualy enter the current date. `CTRL` + `;`

### Explanation of current situation and proposed solution

[image]

Comment: I was about to suggest a global variable or similar to test the table refresh against but this is much more elegant. I would do this and use a button or the like,

Comment: @branislav You mean something like I did on Edit 1? Because I tried that and it's not working. BTW, didn't know about that shortcut. Thx

Comment: No, that is not exactly my point. The *Date update* will still be in the `Worksheet_Change` event, no change there. The point is, that you will not just Refresh the table using some standard Refresh method (e.g. right click > refresh), but you will encapsulate this inside another sub, with disabled events. What is happening: When you refresh the table manualy, excel triggers the worksheet change event and runs the event code. To prevent this, we use `EnableEvents = False`. When you refresh the table after such line, no events will trigger, thus no dates will be updated.

Comment: @ViníciusAffonso, I have added some diagram to better explain the problem. May it help.